Power Apps, Canvas app: "Error Network Error when using Patch Function: An error occurred on the server"
I have a power apps, Canvas app.  It will not allow me to update Any date field and save.  The Save button is typical
SubmitForm(formName);
Refresh(ListNameDataSource);
ResetForm(formName);

I can update other fields, but I get an error message on this one.  Then after I get this error "Network error when using Patch function: An error occurred on the server."  message, the entire form is locked up and it says I'm editing it even after I have left it.
At first it would allow me to update a drop down field, but as soon as I tried to update a date field, I got the error, and now the I get the error on everything.
I am NOT using the patch function- just submit form
In the past I tried ripping out the content of the form, and put items back, and it worked again.  I modified the list by adding a field, and adding a choice to a choice type field in the list.  After I made these changes, I got this error after a long time of this error not being there.
I get the popup in a red bar across the top and it will not allow the save through the save button with the forementioned code.

What data source are you writing to? Do all the form controls pass the data validation in the data source? For example, a SharePoint list might have data validation set up that your form does not adhere to. That would lead to such an error message

The form used to work and update the field.  The same DataCard and field updated the list with no problems.  At some point, certain fields - all date fields now throw this error if I try to update them.  Other fields that have comoboxes don't trigger this error.  These date fields on the form have the date picker control on them, the fields on the list are date.    The only reference I found before is that a control somewhere is corrupt and I have to delete and add again.  This has happened before and I had to rip them all out and add them back.  It cleared the error.  It there a better way?
